# Can I use the new @me.com address as a full feature mailbox?

Tags: ios, icloud

When setting up iCloud in my iOS 5 iPhone 4, there is a new @me.com address created (Settings > iCloud > Account > Advanced > Mail

Is this new @me.com a full feature mailbox?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes - iCloud includes full mail service - webmail, IMAP and iOS for free and not counting against your free 5 Gb of cloud storage quota.

http://www.apple.com/icloud/ mentions that iCloud is free with iOS 5. Enjoy!

Answer (score 3):

I've been using my mac.com and me.com address as my main address since iTools day (when the predecessor to Mac.com was free). Never had any reason to use anything else. I have gmail, but only use it for business emails mostly.

iCloud has a web interface for it, and the Mail.app on iDevices and Macs all use it for their main account. Works well most of the time, though there were a few hiccups tonight with the server authenticating my password. But that seems to have passed.

Answer (score 3):

@bmike is correct that iCloud is a full mail service. But, it counts against your free 5 GB of cloud storage:

From [Apple](http://www.apple.com/icloud/features/):

> Free gets you a lot. When you sign up for iCloud, you automatically get 5GB of free storage. And that’s plenty of room, because of the way
>   iCloud stores your content. Your purchased music, movies, apps, books,
>   and TV shows — as well as your Photo Stream — don’t count against your
>   free storage. That 5GB goes a long way for your mail, documents,
>   account information, settings, and other app data. And if you need
>   more storage, you can easily purchase an upgrade right from your
>   device.